# What is the order of assignments inside a default move constructor?

Tags: c++, memory, move-semantics, allocator, move-constructor

I am currently working on a custom allocator in c++. This allocator has to defragment its memory on a regular basis, by shifting the memory and objects around. These shifts are always downward, meaning that the address of a moved memory chunk always decreases when it gets moved. There is no problem doing so when the old memory chunk and the new memory chunk don't overlap. If they are overlapping I first must move the object into a temporary area outside of the allocator memory and then move it back to the new memory chunk.

If std::is_trivially_move_constructible is true for the moved type, then I might save this extra move to a temporary memory chunk if the order of assignments inside a default move constructor is well defined. This leads to my question: Is the order of assignments well defined or is it platform specific?

Comment: Can't any such object be moved manually, e.g. by [std::memmove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove)?

Comment: Which "assignments" are you referring to?

Comment: Technically, data members are constructed in the order they are listed in the class definition. Which may or may not be the same as the order they are laid out in memory; that order is only guaranteed between members with the same access. In practice, a trivial copy/move constructor is likely to degenerate to a `memcpy` call or similar, under as-if rule. Even still, the compiler could theoretically copy front to back, or back to front, or odd bytes first then even bytes; I don't think such hypothetical implementations would be non-conforming.

Comment: "*This allocator has to defragment its memory on a regular basis, by shifting the memory and objects around.*" Um, you can't really do that. Not unless you have *complete knowledge* of which values in those objects are pointers and which ones are not. And FYI: pointers can be stored in integer values. If you move an object, without adjusting the value of everything that points into that piece of memory, you've broken something.

Comment: Garbage collection using memmove has been proven to be slow. You might be on the wrong path, beware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard (Section 15.8.1 [class.copy.ctor])

> (14) The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X
>   performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. [ Note:
>   Default member initializers of non-static data members are ignored.
>   See also the example in 15.6.2. — end note ] The order of
>   initialization is the same as the order of initialization of bases and
>   members in a user-defined constructor (see 15.6.2)

Following the link leads us to
Section 15.6.2 [class.base.init]

> (13.3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they
>   were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>   of the mem-initializer s)

---

Not quite answering the question to the point, but as Igor Tandetnik also said in his answer, it is legal to transform a trivial constructor into a  `std::memmove`

Answer (score 0):

> **[basic.types]/3** For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`.

So for a trivially copyable type, it would be safe to simply copy the bytes, e.g. with `memmove`. You can test for this trait with `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

Note that *trivially move constructible* is a necessary but not sufficient condition of being trivially copyable:

> **[class]/6** A *trivially copyable class* is a class:
>
> (6.1) — where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator (12.8, 13.5.3) is either deleted or trivial,
>
> (6.2) — that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, and
>
> (6.3) — that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor (12.4).

Comment: I've referred to this instead of a vague 'all compilers support memmove'